# PHP Socket_read returns nothing

Tags: php, html, sockets, websocket

I can successfully write some text to my socket (I know this because it returns the byte length), but when I try socket_read it returns and empty string. I've tried socket_recv with the MSG_WAITALL parameter and it returns 0 bytes. What's going on?
The weird thing is, I can receive this kind of message:

```
$input = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$input .= "Host: mydomain.com\r\n";
$input .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
```

Here's my full code:

```
<?php
echo "loading socket...";

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$result = socket_connect($socket, "fefansoftware.com", 80);

$input = "hello world";
echo socket_write($socket, $input, strlen($input));

$buffer = 'This is my buffer.';
if ($bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 2048, MSG_WAITALL)) {
    echo $bytes . " bytes received";
    echo $buffer;
}else {
    echo "read failed";
}

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Why can't I receive a hello world message but I can receive a "HEAD / HTTP1.1..." message?

Comment: Web servers use protocols to send and receive data, the first one is in http which is the expected protocol seeing as you connect to port 80. The second one is just some text. Which the server probably ignores.

Comment: So how can I simply send and receive some text so clients can communicate with each other?